# In which way does Angular resolve duplicate directive/component selectors?

Tags: angular

If I include two modules which both define a component or directive with the same selector (lets say `a[routerLink]`).

ModuleA defines directive with selector `a[routerLink]`

ModuleB defines directive with selector `a[routerLink]`

AppModule includes both modules and uses `<a routerLink="..."></a>` in its template.

Which directive is used then? How does Angular resolve which component/directive is chosen at runtime? Is the behaviour documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of components with the same selector declared in two separate modules Angular template parser will look for the closest component in whole application tree. Here you can see working example (just click on the link that'll render second 'hello' component declared inside `TestModule`:
[StackBlitz - example of two components with same selector](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ws9xgv)

Answer (score 3):

You should get this error message

```
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: ${componentTypeNames.join(',')}
```

from https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L663-L665

You need to ensure yourself that components are declared or imported into a single NgModule do not conflict.

If conflicting components are not imported or declared in the same module there won't be a conflict.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10552#issuecomment-242998180

Comment: Thanks for the answer Günter. I clarified my question. What i was asking is, if two modules define the same selector and I include both of them.

Comment: Right, directives don't cause conflicts. They'll just all be applied.

Comment: The funny thing is, that it is working in my case. I am overwriting the routerLink directive in one module. If i import this module in my AppModule, my own routerLink is used instead of the one from the general RouterModule. I am wondering how it works.

Comment: Right I updated my answer and my comment. You can have multiple directives with the same selector as other components or directives.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is the order in which they are applied documented? I'd expect that they follow `declarations` order and module hierarchy, similarly to AngularJS (minus `priority`), but tbh I never was interested enough to clarify this.

Comment: @estus I'm pretty sure there is no defined order.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks, I'll make sure when I'll be up to it. I really hope that the team is not that reckless to leave this out of control.

Comment: I think the order is explicitly and intentionally not defined. That would be way to fragile. I don't see where the order would even matter.

Comment: @estus I always look at this test https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/compiler/test/template_parser/template_parser_spec.ts#L896-L917

Comment: Interesting, seems I'm wrong again. I'd try to avoid depending on that though.

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/joWru6l0TjnHi00IkItu Change order in AppModule and look at console. Does it make sense? Or I did not take something into account

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the outline. And the order is also affected by DI (instance of A is injected into B), as it's expected.

Comment: For DI it should be stated in the docs, and here it's much more important.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/compiler/test/template_parser/template_parser_spec.ts#L1259-L1271